# is there a better way to write this switch statement javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Consider the following switch statement:

```
let doAttack = (firstAttacker, secondAttacker, statusOfBattle) => {
  statusOfBattle = createNonHitMessages(secondAttacker, firstAttacker, statusOfBattle);

  switch(statusOfBattle) {
    case statusOfBattle.enemyDodged && statusOfBattle.enemyBlocked:
      console.log('enemy Attack');
      break;
    case statusOfBattle.attackerDodged && statusOfBattle.attackerBlocked:
      console.log('attacker Attack');
      break;
    case statusOfBattle.enemyDodged:
      console.log('enemy Attack');
      break;
    case statusOfBattle.enemyBlocked:
      console.log('enemey Attack');
      break;
    case statusOfBattle.attackerBlocked:
      console.log('attacker attack');
      break;
    case statusOfBattle.attackerDodged:
      console.log('attacker attack');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return statusOfBattle
}
```

`enemeyDodged`, `enemeyBlocked`, `attackerBlocked` and `attackerDodged` will all return `true` or `false`.

I really do not want to write a giant if statement, I have nothing against it, aside from it doesn't look very clean when I have this many conditions.

if an `if` statement is the only way to go great, but I was hoping that I could check boolean values in a switch statement like this so I could keep this clean and readable.

I clearly don't understand the limitations of switch statements.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: You could set up all the potential values and their corresponding actions in an array of objects and then loop over the array, checking each object for a match and, when the match is found, perform its action.

Comment: @ScottMarcus could you provide an example?

Comment: First, can you explain how the `statusOfBattle` object could be equal to two properties of itself?

Comment: `case` is short for an `===` comparison. So you're testing `statusOfBattle === (statusOfBattle.enemyDodged && statusOfBattle.enemyBlocked)`. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: @ScottMarcus if it was a recursive structure  and javascript supported operator overriding. Clearly something is wrong though.

Comment: One thing that will really make it look shorter (even with an if/else) is if you would rename the variable you access over 10 times to something shorter like `status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `switch` works - it evaluates the thing between parentheses, in your case `statusOfBattle`, and executes the case for the value equal to the thing. Your statement wouldn't match any case because a property of `statusOfBattle` won't be equal to the `statusOfBattle` object itself.

I don't completely understand how to determine who attacks, but regardless you could try using a simple if/else statement with some logical operators:

```
let doAttack = (firstAttacker, secondAttacker, statusOfBattle) => {
  statusOfBattle = createNonHitMessages(secondAttacker, firstAttacker, statusOfBattle);

  if (statusOfBattle.attackerDodged && !statusOfBattle.enemyBlocked) {
    return 'attacker attack';
  } else if (statusOfBattle.attackerBlocked) {
    return 'attacker attack';
  } else {
    return 'enemy attack';
  }
}
```

Make you can even make a shorter, better-looking version with an `?` expression:

```
let doAttack = (firstAttacker, secondAttacker, statusOfBattle) => {
  statusOfBattle = createNonHitMessages(secondAttacker, firstAttacker, statusOfBattle);

  return statusOfBattle.attackerDodged ? 'attacker attack' : 'enemy attack';
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid if statement but it seems there’s no other way. Hahahah.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (a) {
    case x:
        // do something
        break;
    case y:
        // do something else
        break;
    case z:
        // do third thing
        break;
}
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
if (a === x) {
    // do something
} else if (a === y) {
    // do something else
} else if (a === z) {
    // do third thing
}
```

So your code won't work, because it's testing things like:

```
if (statusOfBattle === (statusOfBattle.enemyDodged && statusOfBattle.enemyBlocked))
```

Since `statusOfBattle` is an object and `statusOfBattle.enemyDodged && statusOfBattle.enemyBlocked` is either `true` or `false`, they will never be equal.

I'm not a big fan of this style, but you can do what you want by starting with:

```
switch (true) {
    ...
}
```